# GtkWidget: Alternative for deprecated "double-buffered" property?

Tags: c, opengl, gtk, x11, gtk3

I've derived my own widget type from `GtkWidget` in order to use it as a drawing surface for OpenGL. To give OpenGL control over the underlying X11 Window, I need to disable the widget's double buffering - else the whole rendering result will be drawn over by GTK's buffer swap.

However, `gtk_widget_set_double_buffered` and the `"double-buffered"` property have been deprecated in the current version of GTK+3 for being too platform-dependent.

Is there a way to disable double buffering on the GDK or X11 level instead?

Comment: Just because it's deprecated doesn't mean you can't use it. It won't be guaranteed to work in all situations, but that depends on the situation you want. What minimum exact version of GTK+ do you need to support? And if 3.16 is too new, do you need Wayland OpenGL support? What about [this](https://github.com/andrepiske/tegtkgl)?

Comment: That's right, but usually a feature is deprecated because there is a better solution to the same problem - also I'd like my code to keep working with future versions of GTK+. I'm actually working on a [fork](https://github.com/fknorr/gtkglcanvas) of that repository.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather old question, but I'll give it a shot.

In any even slightly more recent context (i.e. with GTK+ >= 3.16, which is over 6 years old by now), I guess the best solution would be to avoid rolling your own OpenGL widget and just use `Gtk.GLArea` instead: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.GLArea.html

Alternatively, if you happen to be stuck with an ancient GTK+ version, maybe on an embedded device, then there aren't many options besides `gtk_widget_set_double_buffered` (see also [https://people.gnome.org/~shaunm/girdoc/C/Gtk.Widget.set_double_buffered.html](https://people.gnome.org/%7Eshaunm/girdoc/C/Gtk.Widget.set_double_buffered.html)): this does not set any X11/Xorg window flags or similar, but just changes the internal event handling of GTK+ to either send draw calls to an offscreen buffer, or directly to the visible surface.

Note that this offscreen buffer is completely separate from anything involving X or OpenGL.